# How to find the key by comparing from value of a map in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have a list which is having few urls. I am iterating over a map to find where the item from the list exists in the map. If value exists it should return the corresponding map key.

Here is the code:

```
def map= [:]
List<String> list = ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
for (project in activeJobs) {

    scm = project.scm;
    //println("${project.name}: " +
      //      "repositories: ${scm.repositories.collectMany{ it.getURIs() }}")
    def uriName = scm.repositories.collectMany{ it.getURIs() }
    uriName.eachWithIndex { item, index ->
        //println item
        uriName = uriName[index].toString().toLowerCase()
        map.put(project.name, uriName)
    }

}
list.each { url ->

    //println url
    //def item = map.find { value -> url }
    //println item
    //println url
    print map.find { it.value == url }?.key

}
```

Last print statement always returns null.

Comment: can you try "print map.find { it.value == "$url" }?.key" this once..

Answer (score 1):

Using `findResults` on `Map`:

```
List<String> list = ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
Map<String, String> map = [a: "url1", b: "url2", c: "url5", d: "url3"]

assert map.findResults { k, v -> v in list ? k : null } == ['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the following JUnit Test:

```
@Test
void testit(){
  def map = ["k1" : "url1", "k2" : "url2", "k3" : "url3"]
  def list = ["url1", "url2", "url3"]
  list.each { url ->
  print map.find { it.value == url }?.key

  }
}
```

And the output was:

```
k1k2k3
```

Could you post more of your code if it still doesn't work, but I don't think your problem is here.

Sam

Comment: I'm sure you have - tried it but have your printed the whole contents of the map to see what's in there?

Comment: Yeah, infact getClass().name always gives java.lang.String for key and value pair

Comment: What does getURIs return?

Comment: Ah just spotted something.  Your code is overwriting your url values with the last one?  Will post above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120273/discussion-between-user-dev-and-sam).

Answer (score 0):

```
uriName = uriName[index].toString().toLowerCase()
```

Is the problem here